# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while switching from owl-api 3.5 to 4.x

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, owl-api

I've used the owl-api version 3.5 and now I would like to switch to Version 4, but I get a runtime exception. Like in the following example code (which works fine with version 3.5) a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError it thrown every time invoking the function "manager.addAxiom(...)".

```
WLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://example.com/owlapi/families");
OWLOntology ont = manager.createOntology(ontologyIRI);      
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

OWLIndividual john = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#John"));
OWLIndividual mary = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#Mary"));
OWLObjectProperty hasWife = factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#hasWife"));
OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom axiom1 = factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(hasWife, john, mary);

manager.addAxiom(ont, axiom1);
...
```

The whole exeption which is thrown says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.addAxiom(Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology;Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAxiom;)Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/parameters/ChangeApplied;
at de.ifak.Writer.OWL.Example.OWLMinimalTest.main(OWLMinimalTest.java:26)
```

I've tested the code in a clean Java project and added the owl-api dependencies manual and later with maven. I've testet it with version 4.0.2 and 4.1.0-RC2. Both have shown the same behavior.

I couldn't find any solution for that. So I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution by myself.
If I change the code

```
manager.addAxiom(ont, axiom1);
```

to

```
Set<OWLAxiom> axiomsToAdd = new HashSet<OWLAxiom>();
axiomsToAdd.add(axiom1);        
manager.addAxioms(ont, axiomsToAdd);
```

all works fine, even with version 4.1 of the owl-api.

Edit:
Ok I made a mistake. It works fine with version 4.0.2 but with version 4.1 I get the same exception when I call:

```
manager.addAxioms(ont, axiomsToAdd);
```

like when I call:

```
manager.addAxiom(ont, axiom1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The addAxiom method is still there but its return type has changed. Are you assigning the value returned to a variable?

Comment: No, I found what went wrong. I had old versions (v3.5 and v4.0.2) of the owl-api in the classpath. As I removed this versions from classpath the exception disappeared. Now it works also with version 4.1 of the owl-api.